# Crystal Reports - Total Count

Tags: crystal-reports

looking to show an employee total on a report which has the following.

The report shows, by company divisions, count of employees to have had their annual assessment, I also wish to show total employee count per division so we would show

North Division - 50 employees had assessment  out of 170 employees
East Division - 30 employees had assessment out of 50 employees

I cant seem to figure how to show the total count by division.
any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you include the table structures for the Employee and Annual Asessment tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all; you need to group your data by Division.

You then need add a running total:  Set it to count a a field displayed on each line (such as employee id). Then click in the "Evaluate" section - "Use a formula".  Click the X-2 button to open the formula editor.

Your formula will be dependant on your data.  You want it to output "True" for employees who have had their assement and false otherwise. [*]

Then in the "Reset" section, click "on change of group" and select your division group.

Now place your running total in the group footer of the division group.

[*] if this does not work, you will need to create a formula that outputs 1 or 0, on every line depending on whether the employee has had an assessment.  Then create a sum on this formula to count the employees.

There are multiple methods of achieving what you want.  Google "Crystal Reports Conditional Sum" for more answers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I see where you are heading with this, however the annual assessment data is in another table so it is not as simple as a  yes/no column in the employee table so when I implement this grouping it only pulls employees who have had their assessment, this part is ok it Groups by Division then Assessment Outcome and its displays on a bar graph, what I would like to also show is the 50 out of (total)170  have had assessments.

Comment: Thanks got it, not exactly the way I wanted to do it as I had to create a sub-report due to formatting etc But, it's working.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  I have a love / hate relationship with crystal. Some times its brilliant - other times I tear my hair out.